# View with paged output - how to alter number of pages?

Tags: 7, paging, views

I use Views 7.x-3.8.
I have view "taxonomy_term". It has Paged output, full pager. Number of pages (the total number of pages) is set to 100, Items per page = 10.
Now I want to show all pages for users with proper permission.

I tried to set pager option 'total_pages' to empty string in hook_views_pre_execute():

```
function MYMODULE_views_pre_execute(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'taxonomy_term') {
    if (user_access('view all pages')) {
      $view->query->pager->options['total_pages'] = '';
    }
  }
}
```

It actually works with pager: users with permission 'view all pages' can view page #101, #102 and so on, but nodes on these pages (more than #100) are the same as on page #100. It means that query has not changed, and query limit is still 1000 (10 items x 100 pages).
I tried

```
$view->query->set_limit(0);
```

in hook_views_pre_execute() and

```
$view->query->set_limit(0);
$query->set_limit(0);
```

in hook_views_query_alter(), but it's not working.

I also tried to set $view->query->offset and $view->offset manually:

```
$view->query->offset = $view->offset = $view->query->pager->current_page * $view->query->limit;
```

with no effect.

What am I missing? How to change number of view' total pages AND query results programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did it:

```
function MYMODULE_views_pre_execute(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'taxonomy_term') {
    if (user_access('view all pages')) {
      $view->query->pager->options['total_pages'] = NULL;
      $query = $view->build_info['query'];
      $offset = $view->query->pager->current_page * $view->query->limit;
      $query->range($offset, $view->query->limit);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't need to do this exact thing, but seeing how you've solved your problem pointed me in the right direction for mine. Thank you!